# Automorphism group of $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: group-theory, roots-of-unity, automorphism-group

Consider the group of all complex roots of unity, $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ (where both groups are additive groups). I was wondering what its automorphism group is ?

Comment: Maybe it helps to first consider the automorphism group of the rationals, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/511796/automorphism-from-bbb-q-to-bbb-q

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: $\Bbb Q/\Bbb Z$ is a direct sum of Prüfer $p$-groups and and each of those has at least one automorphism for each unit of the p-adic integers, see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1048116/automorphisms-of-the-pr%c3%bcfer-group). In fact,   ${\rm Aut}(\Bbb Q/\Bbb Z)\cong \prod_p \Bbb Z_p^{\times}$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of looking just at automorphisms of this abelian group, let’s look at endomorphisms to get a ring and then the automorphisms are the units of this ring.

The torsion group $G = \mathbf Q/\mathbf Z$ is the *direct sum* of its subgroups $G_p$ of $p$-power elements. That is a fancy way of saying nontrivial roots of unity are unique products of finitely many nontrivial roots of unity of $p$-power order for different primes $p$. An endomorphism of $G$ induces an endomorphism of each $G_p$ and a set of choices $(f_p)_p$ of endomorphisms of each $G_p$ as $p$ runs over the primes defines an endomorphism of $G$. This bijection between elements of $\prod_p {\rm End}(G_p)$ and elements of $G$ shows the endomorphisms of $G$ are the *direct product* of the endomorphisms of each $G_p$.

What are the endomorphisms of the group $G_p$, which is isomorphic to the group of $p$-power roots of unity? They are the $p$-adic integers (each one acting as an exponent on all of $G_p$). Therefore the endomorphism ring of $G$ is $\prod_p \mathbf Z_p$, and passing to units shows the answer to your question (what are the automorphisms of $G$?) is $\prod_p \mathbf Z_p^\times$.

This answer is perhaps much more sophisticated than you expected (if you never heard of $p$-adic integers), because the description of the endomorphisms of the additive group $\mathbf Q$ is much simpler: they are the multiplication maps $r \mapsto sr$ for different rationals $s$, so the automorphism group of $\mathbf Q$ is $\mathbf Q^\times$. The lesson here is that the (additive) quotient group $\mathbf Q/\mathbf Z$ is a more complicated object than the additive group $\mathbf Q$: the former is an infinite torsion group while the latter is an infinite uniquely divisible group.

Comment: Is this group isomorphic to the group of units of the profinite integers $\widehat{\mathbb{Z}}$?

Comment: @Boccherini  yes, but I didn't want to use that terminology.  The endomophism ring is the profinite integers.

Comment: I think your third sentence should stress _distinct_ primes $p$ (to contrast with unique factorization in $\Bbb Z_{>0}$ where repetition of primes (in a somewhat different role) is allowed. (Also there are minor matters as either ignoring or imposing the order in which factors are taken into account, not considering $1$ a candidate $p$-power order element, and allowing an empty product.)

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen I made some edits.