# On the group of roots of unity

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-geometry, galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Here are a few (simple) questions on roots of unity I'm a little confused about.

> Is the automorphism group of the group $\mu_{\infty}$ of all roots of unity $\widehat{\mathbf{Z}}^{\times}$, and what are its orbits?

For the first question, the answer should be yes because the automorphism group of a finite cyclic group of order $n$ is $(\mathbf{Z}/n)^{\times}$.

> Suppose I define $G\subset\mu_{\infty}$ to be the **union** (not the subgroup generated by) of the subgroups of the form $\mu_{p^n-1}$ for $p$ prime and $n\ge 1$. Do we have $G=\mu_{\infty}$? Does $G$ generate $\mu_{\infty}$? Is $G$ dense in the circle group $T\subset\mathbf{C}^{\times}$ with respect to the topology induced by the complex topology?

I would expect the answer to the first question to be no, but I don't know about the second and third.

Comment: For the second question: take any $m$th root of unity, then it belongs to $G$, because by Dirichlet's theorem on arithmetic progressions there is a prime of the form $p=am+1$.

Comment: (And if $p$ is fixed, then we don't get any $p^k$-th roots of unity.)

Comment: For the 1st question. The map $r\mapsto e^{2i\pi r}$ gives an iso between ${\bf Q}/{\bf Z}$ and $\mu_\infty$. Hence the answer is yes by https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4458363/automorphism-group-of-mathbbq-mathbbz